# Kotlin read and display data from Google Sheets

Tags: kotlin

Can somebody help me accomplish what I am trying to. I have spent hours watching videos and surfing Google to do it myself. But, I couldn't as there's no help I could find to read just one cell value from Google Sheets and I couldn't also find code for Kotlin.

All what I want is to display the value in cell B2 in my Google sheets in a textview on MainActivity.

I am new to Android app development.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

i have code for to get the value from google sheets let me share it to you.

First of all  you need to create one spreadsheet and you need to create your api key to get access to spreadsheet api.

> MY SpreadSheet data

[image: sheet data]

--> When you create spread sheet in file options -> publish to web. and it will generate a link.
-> get the sheets id from that link. it will be like

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/your-id-//edit#gid=0

--> On given url you have to put your sheets id sheet name and the api key that you have generated from [google console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=fluted-castle-340213)

From generated url you can get the json format of your data into spreadsheet.
Your url will look like this.

> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/YOUR_SHEET_ID/values/YOUR_SHEET_NAME?alt=json&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Open this url into browser and get the json format of your data from spreadsheet.

After getting the data

Here is the code to retrive the data from spreadsheet.

first you need a model class to get the data from json.

```
class model {
        // variables for our first name,
        // last name, email and avatar
        private var first_name: String? = null
        private var last_name: String? = null
        private var email: String? = null

        constructor(first_name: String, last_name: String, email: String){
            this.first_name = first_name;
            this.last_name = last_name;
            this.email = email;
        }

        fun getFirst_name(): String? {
            return first_name
        }

        fun setFirst_name(first_name: String?) {
            this.first_name = first_name
        }

        fun getLast_name(): String? {
            return last_name
        }

        fun setLast_name(last_name: String?) {
            this.last_name = last_name
        }

        fun getEmail(): String? {
            return email
        }

        fun setEmail(email: String?) {
            this.email = email
        }

}
```

BaseModel.kt

```
class BaseModel {
    @SerializedName("range")
    @Expose
    private var range: String? = null

    @SerializedName("majorDimension")
    @Expose
    private var majorDimension: String? = null

    @SerializedName("values")
    @Expose
    private var values: List<List<model?>?>? = null

    fun getRange(): String? {
        return range
    }

    fun setRange(range: String?) {
        this.range = range
    }

    fun getMajorDimension(): String? {
        return majorDimension
    }

    fun setMajorDimension(majorDimension: String?) {
        this.majorDimension = majorDimension
    }

    fun getValues(): List<List<model?>?>? {
        return values
    }

    fun setValues(values: List<List<model?>?>?) {
        this.values = values
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/idRVUsers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/user_rv_item" />

    <!--we are adding progress bar for thepurpose of loading-->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/idPBLoading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

user_rv_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <!--image view for displaying user image-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idIVUser"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <!--text view for displaying first name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVFirstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVUser"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVUser"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <!--text view for displaying last name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVLastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idTVFirstName"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVUser"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVUser"
            android:text="Last Name"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <!--text view for displaying user email-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idTVLastName"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVUser"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVUser"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

rv_adapter.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class UserRVAdapter(modelArraylist: ArrayList<model>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<UserRVAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    // variable for our array list and context.
    private val userModalArrayList: ArrayList<model> = modelArraylist
    private val context: Context? = null

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val firstNameTV: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVFirstName)
        var lastNameTV: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVLastName)
        var emailTV: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVEmail)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.user_rv_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // getting data from our array list in our modal class.
        // getting data from our array list in our modal class.
        val userModal: model = userModalArrayList[position]

        // on the below line we are setting data to our text view.

        // on the below line we are setting data to our text view.
        holder.firstNameTV?.setText(userModal.getFirst_name())
        holder.lastNameTV?.setText(userModal.getLast_name())
        holder.emailTV?.setText(userModal.getEmail())
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userModalArrayList.size
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
 import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.ProgressBar
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.android.volley.Request
    import com.android.volley.Response
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
    import org.json.JSONException
    import org.json.JSONObject
    
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private var userModalArrayList: ArrayList<model>? = null
        private var userRVAdapter: UserRVAdapter? = null
        private var userRV: RecyclerView? = null
        private var loadingPB: ProgressBar? = null
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            userModalArrayList = ArrayList()
            userRV = findViewById(R.id.idRVUsers)
            loadingPB = findViewById(R.id.idPBLoading)
            getDataFromAPI()
        }
    
        private fun getDataFromAPI() {
            val url=
          "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/YOUR_SHEET_ID/values/YOUR_SHEET_NAME?alt=json&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
    
            val jsonObjectRequest =
                JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    url,
                    null,
                    object : Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
                        override fun onResponse(response: JSONObject) {
                            loadingPB!!.visibility = View.GONE
                            try {
                                // val feedObj = response.getJSONObject("")
                                val entryArray = response.getJSONArray("values")
    
                                for (i in 1 until entryArray.length()) {
                                    val entryObj = entryArray.getJSONArray(i)
                                    val firstName =
                                        entryObj[2].toString()
                                    val lastName = entryObj[3].toString()
                                    //  entryObj.getJSONObject("gsx\$lastname").getString("\$t")
                                    val email = entryObj[1].toString()
    
                                    userModalArrayList!!.add(model(firstName, lastName, email))
    
    
                                    // passing array list to our adapter class.
                                    userRVAdapter = UserRVAdapter(userModalArrayList!!)
    
                                    // setting layout manager to our recycler view.
                                    userRV!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    
                                    // setting adapter to our recycler view.
                                    userRV!!.adapter = userRVAdapter
                                }
                            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    object : Response.ErrorListener {
                        override fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError?) {
                            // handline on error listener method.
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Fail to get data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                    })
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    }
```

> You can use this code to get data from your whole google spread sheet.

Comment: kindly accept the answer so that other users can get the base idea of the topic,. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest making google sheet [public](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), then you can access it for example as csv or in other formats, but csv is simplest. You can construct url based on sheet id:

```
val url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/${id}/pub?output=csv"
```

You can get contents for example using [ktor](https://ktor.io/):

```
suspend fun getUrlAsString(url: String): String {
    val client = HttpClient(Android) {
    }
    return client.get<String>(url)
}
```

Example on how to parse csv, but you can use some library or parse text yourself, it's pretty simple:

```
fun parseCsv(text: String): List<Map<String, String>> {
    val reader = CSVReaderBuilder(StringReader(text))
            .build()
    val lines = reader.readAll()
    val firstLine = lines.removeAt(0)

    val result = lines.map { line ->
        firstLine.mapIndexed { index, label ->
            label to line[index]
        }.toMap()
    }
    if (result.size > 4)
        println(result[4])
    return result

}
```