# Pulling specific information from Google Sheets into different Google Site pages dynamically (not all info needed based on filtering)

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets-api, google-sites-2016

Is there a way to pull specific information from a Google sheet into a Google site? I’m using Google sheets as a database and need to pull based on specific sorting fields to create live schedules for individual groups on a website. Alternatively, I could program within Sheets (I think) a page for each user group that is pulling from the master page and then publish/embed each page if that makes sense?

e.g. My sheet contains standard day, start time, end time, location, and details, but there are fields for user groups (i.e. students, staff, property, kitchen, etc.) I want to pull the events only for the tagged group and post them on their group's website page). Note some events will be pulled for multiple pages.
Thank you!
Sarah

Comment: Add more specific needs to go further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gviz to get and query google sheet data. For instance
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68948211/15019380

It uses json end point with this url

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
```

where id is the spreadsheet id an gid the sheet id.

You can use 3 modes :

- `/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json`
- `/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv`
- `/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html`

You can add queries for instance `&tq=SELECT+B%2CC%2CD+where+C+contains+%27S%27` (means before encoding `SELECT B,C,D where C contains 'S'`)

Reference : [query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)